# what should I add to the Gradle Dependency?

Tags: java

I have serval activities in my project,
but I don't have any Dependency in Gradle and
I have these imports
and I have errors in these imports like: Appcompat, appcompatActivity, and a lot...

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;
```

so what Dependencies should I add to the Gradle,
this is my Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and I can't run my project, when I sync the project it shows this error

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.ArtifactUtils.toKey(ArtifactUtils.kt:496)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.FullDependencyGraphBuilder.handleDependency(FullDependencyGraphBuilder.kt:130)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.FullDependencyGraphBuilder.handleDependency(FullDependencyGraphBuilder.kt:163)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have run into a Gradle bug.  Take a look at these bug reports in the Google issue tracker:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206947890
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232075280

It seems that if you have a cyclic dependency in your build file(s) you can trigger this bug.

One way to solve it would be to track down the circular dependency and remove it.  Another would be to upgrade to a version of AGP with fixes for the bug(s); see the "fix targeted to" information in the issue reports.